# scheduling with cronjob to run the php file for only one time

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, cron, crontab, cronjob

How do I run the php file only once using the cron jobs. i.e., to schedule task to work on 20/06/2015 10:30:00

I tried something like this :

`30 10 20 6 ? 2015 /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/file/application.php`

but it is not working.

I just want to schedule it for future but do not want to repeat it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: do not use cron. Use [at](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at).

Example:

> `at now + 1 minute`
>   `ls`
>   <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
>   `Job 2 will be executed using /bin/sh`

For 5 ½ hours you could use 330 minutes.

Comment: How to use `at now +5:30` ? it gives an error garbled time.